# Issues with slow page load time on specific pages of my WordPress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

On my WordPress site I have created custom `location` post types and used a page called `single-locations.php` to build out a sort of template to be displayed when displaying each of these post types. The issue I'm having is upon initial page load a blue bar appears on the top and bottom of each of these pages, while the blue bar  at the top goes away a second after the page is finished loading the one all the way at the bottom does not. This has only been happening for these `location` pages and not anywhere else on the site. I have checked my browser for any JavaScript errors on these pages and there are none. Was wondering if anyone had any idea what might be causing this issue?

Here is `single-locations.php`

```
<?php
get_header(); 
nectar_page_header($post->ID); 


//full page
$fp_options = nectar_get_full_page_options();
extract($fp_options);

?>
<?php $phone=get_field("phone_number");
$phoneFormat='<a class="phone-span" href="tel:1-'. $phone . '">' . $phone . '</a>';
$phonefootFormat='<a class="phone-footer-link" href="tel:1-'. $phone . '">' . $phone . '</a>';
$phonebodyFormat='<strong>Call Our Customer Service Team ' . '<a class="phone-span" href="tel:1-' . $phone . '">' . $phone . '</a>' . ' or leave a message below</strong>';
$saved_testimonial_raw=remember_testimonial();
$saved_testimonial=str_replace("'", "\'", $saved_testimonial_raw);
?>


<?php 
$image=get_field('background_image');
$city=get_field('city');
$get_started_page_id = get_field( 'get_started_page', 'options' );
$location_finder_page_id = get_field( 'location_finder_page', 'options' );
$location_get_started_button_text = get_field( 'location_get_started_button_text', 'options' );
$location_finder_button_text = get_field( 'location_finder_button_text', 'options' );
$get_started_button = '<a class="nectar-button large see-through-2 " href="' . get_the_permalink($get_started_page_id) . '" data-color-override="false" data-hover-color-override="false" data-hover-text-color-override="#ffffff">
        <span>' . $location_get_started_button_text . '</span>
    </a>';
?>

<div class="location-banner-section" align="center" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>); padding-top: 10%; padding-bottom: 10%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
    <div>
        <h1 class="location-top"><?php echo $city;?> Pool Cleaning Service</h1> 
    </div>
    <div style= "padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
        <h2 class="location-top"><?php echo'<a style="color: #ffffff;" href="tel:1-' . $phone . '">' . $phone . '</a>';?></h2> 
    </div>
    <?php echo $get_started_button; ?>
</div>


<div class="container-wrap">

    <div class="main-content">

        <?php 
        //display the price chart
        $include_price_chart = get_field('include_price_chart');

        if($include_price_chart):
        ?>
            <section id="price-chart-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <?php echo sal_full_price_chart(); ?>
                </div>
            </section>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
            //display the our specials section 
            $include_specials = get_field( 'include_our_specials_section');

            if($include_specials):
                $specials_options = get_field( 'our_specials' );
                $specials_title = ($specials_options['override_specials_title'] ? $specials_options['override_specials_title'] : 'Our Specials');
                $specials_details = $specials_options['our_specials_details'];
        ?>
            <section id="our-specials-wrapper" class="red-background align-center medium-padding medium-spacing">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="light-text"><?php echo $specials_title ?></h2>
                    <div class="description"><?php echo $specials_details ?></div>
                    <?php echo $get_started_button; ?>
                </div>
            </section>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
        //display the about section
        $include_about_section = get_field('include_about_section_content');

        if($include_about_section):
            $about_section_content = get_field('about_section_content','options');
        ?>
            <section id="about-section-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <?php echo sal_about_section($about_section_content); ?>
                </div>
            </section>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
        //display the testimonials section
        $include_testimonials_section = get_field('include_testimonials_section');

        if($include_testimonials_section):
        ?>
            <section id="testimonials-section-wrapper" class="large-padding medium-top-spacing">
                <div class="container align-center">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[testimonials_widget]'); ?>
                </div>
            </section>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
            //display the our specials section 
            $include_neighborhood_section = get_field( 'include_neighborhood_section');

            if($include_neighborhood_section):
                $neighborhood_options = get_field( 'neighborhood_content' );
                $neighborhood_title = ($neighborhood_options['override_neighborhood_title'] ? $neighborhood_options['override_neighborhood_title'] : 'We\'re In The Neighborhood');
                $neighborhood_details = $neighborhood_options['neighborhood_details'];
                $neighborhood_photo = $neighborhood_options['neighborhood_photo'];
        ?>
            <section id="our-neighborhood-wrapper" class="lightgray-background medium-padding medium-bottom-spacing flex">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span_6">
                            <h2><?php echo $neighborhood_title ?></h2>
                            <div class="description"><?php echo $neighborhood_details ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span_6">
                            <div class="section-photo">
                                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($neighborhood_photo['id'], "large"); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </section>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <div class="container">

            <?php 

            //breadcrumbs
            if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) && !is_home() && !is_front_page() ){ yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>'); } 

             //buddypress
             global $bp; 
             if($bp && !bp_is_blog_page()) echo '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';

             //fullscreen rows
             if($page_full_screen_rows == 'on') echo '<div id="nectar_fullscreen_rows" data-animation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_animation.'" data-row-bg-animation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_bg_img_animation.'" data-animation-speed="'.$page_full_screen_rows_animation_speed.'" data-content-overflow="'.$page_full_screen_rows_content_overflow.'" data-mobile-disable="'.$page_full_screen_rows_mobile_disable.'" data-dot-navigation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_dot_navigation.'" data-footer="'.$page_full_screen_rows_footer.'" data-anchors="'.$page_full_screen_rows_anchors.'">';

                 if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                     the_content(); 

                 endwhile; endif; 

            if($page_full_screen_rows == 'on') echo '</div>'; ?>

        </div><!--/container-->

        <?php 
            //display the call-to-action section 
            $include_cta_section = get_field('include_cta_contact_section');

            if($include_cta_section):
                $cta_section = get_field( 'cta_section' );
                $cta_title = ($cta_section['override_section_title'] ? $cta_section['override_section_title'] : 'Call our Residential Pool Customer Service Team');
        ?>
            <section id="contact-cta-wrapper" class="red-background align-center medium-padding medium-top-spacing light-text">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="light-text"><?php echo $cta_title ?></h2>

                    <div>
                        <h2><?php echo'<a href="tel:1-' . $phone . '">' . $phone . '</a>';?></h2> 
                    </div>

                    <a class="nectar-button large see-through-2 " href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($location_finder_page_id) ?>" data-color-override="false" data-hover-color-override="false" data-hover-text-color-override="#ffffff;">
                        <span><?php echo $location_finder_button_text ?></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="widget-container" class="align-center">
            <div class="widget-row" style="padding-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 5%; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;">
                <?php $review=get_field('yext_review'); echo $review;?>
            </div>  
        </div>

    </div><!--/main-content-->

</div><!--/container-wrap-->
<script>sessionStorage.setItem('lastphone','<?php echo $phoneFormat;?>');</script>
<script>sessionStorage.setItem('lastphonefoot','<?php echo $phonefootFormat;?>');</script>
<script>sessionStorage.setItem('lastphonebody','<?php echo $phonebodyFormat;?>');</script>

<?php $post_id=get_the_ID(); ?>
<script>sessionStorage.setItem('postid','<?php echo $post_id;?>');</script>

<script>sessionStorage.setItem('pricechart','<?php echo do_shortcode("[price_chart]"); ?>');</script>
<script>
sessionStorage.setItem('testimonial','<?php echo $saved_testimonial;?>');
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
?>
```

Themes `page.php`

```
<?php 

get_header(); 
nectar_page_header($post->ID); 

//full page
$fp_options = nectar_get_full_page_options();
extract($fp_options);

?>

<div class="container-wrap">

    <div class="<?php if($page_full_screen_rows != 'on') echo 'container'; ?> main-content">

        <div class="row">

            <?php 

            //breadcrumbs
            if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) && !is_home() && !is_front_page() ){ yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>'); } 

             //buddypress
             global $bp; 
             if($bp && !bp_is_blog_page()) echo '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';

             //fullscreen rows
             if($page_full_screen_rows == 'on') echo '<div id="nectar_fullscreen_rows" data-animation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_animation.'" data-row-bg-animation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_bg_img_animation.'" data-animation-speed="'.$page_full_screen_rows_animation_speed.'" data-content-overflow="'.$page_full_screen_rows_content_overflow.'" data-mobile-disable="'.$page_full_screen_rows_mobile_disable.'" data-dot-navigation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_dot_navigation.'" data-footer="'.$page_full_screen_rows_footer.'" data-anchors="'.$page_full_screen_rows_anchors.'">';

                 if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                     the_content(); 

                 endwhile; endif; 

            if($page_full_screen_rows == 'on') echo '</div>'; ?>

        </div><!--/row-->

    </div><!--/container-->

</div><!--/container-wrap-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Themes `single.php`:

```
<?php 

get_header(); 
nectar_page_header($post->ID); 

//full page
$fp_options = nectar_get_full_page_options();
extract($fp_options);

?>

<div class="container-wrap">

    <div class="<?php if($page_full_screen_rows != 'on') echo 'container'; ?> main-content">

        <div class="row">

            <?php 

            //breadcrumbs
            if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) && !is_home() && !is_front_page() ){ yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>'); } 

             //buddypress
             global $bp; 
             if($bp && !bp_is_blog_page()) echo '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';

             //fullscreen rows
             if($page_full_screen_rows == 'on') echo '<div id="nectar_fullscreen_rows" data-animation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_animation.'" data-row-bg-animation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_bg_img_animation.'" data-animation-speed="'.$page_full_screen_rows_animation_speed.'" data-content-overflow="'.$page_full_screen_rows_content_overflow.'" data-mobile-disable="'.$page_full_screen_rows_mobile_disable.'" data-dot-navigation="'.$page_full_screen_rows_dot_navigation.'" data-footer="'.$page_full_screen_rows_footer.'" data-anchors="'.$page_full_screen_rows_anchors.'">';

                 if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                     the_content(); 

                 endwhile; endif; 

            if($page_full_screen_rows == 'on') echo '</div>'; ?>

        </div><!--/row-->

    </div><!--/container-->

</div><!--/container-wrap-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Is the site live? Can you post a url?

Comment: can you show some code? it's next to impossible to make an educated suggestion without it

Comment: @danwebb I am creating the site for someone else so I don't think they want me to post the url publicly right now. I can post code. I know it is a little hard to work with but even just a few suggestions as far as what to look into would be helpful.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Just posted the code for the `single-locations.php` file

Comment: My best guess on the blue bars is theme related. As for the slow page load,are you coding the custom post template in the same pattern as the theme's default post templates? Perhaps post the theme's default post template code as well?

Comment: @danwebb hmm so I copied the `page.php` file and added from there. Let me pull  up the default post template.

Comment: @danwebb I posted the themes `page.php` and `single.php` I believe the `single.php` would be the default.

Comment: Thanks. To confirm, this only occurs the first time those pages are loaded? For example, if you refresh the page or go to a new page then come back it loads normally?

Comment: @danwebb no it also happens when I refresh the page.

Comment: See what the results of running the slow pages on: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

vs on the pages that load normally

Comment: If your custom post type is set to hierarchical, changing it to false can speed things up as well.

Comment: @danwebb no it's not but good to know.